# How to pass parameter from AWS Step Functions to PowerShell AWS Lambda?

Tags: powershell, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Into simple AWS Lambda PowerShell script I'm passing parameter called **tokens** in JSON form:

```
{ "tokens": "ABC123" }
```

This is being read by Script as variable **$LambdaInput.tokens** which is expected by Lambda script by [design](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/powershell-handler.html).

Inside Step Function template I have specified Parameter **tokens**:

```
  {
    "Comment": "Start Script",
    "StartAt": "PowerShellScript1",
    "States": {
      "PowerShellScript1": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
        "Parameters": {
          "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:XYZ:function:PowerShellScript1:$LATEST",
          "Payload": {
            "Input": {
              "tokens": "ABC123"
            }
          }
        },
        "End": true,
        "TimeoutSeconds": 60
      }
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately my Lambda script can't recongnize the parameter. I expect it's not being inserted as variable **$LambdaInput.tokens**.

Is there different Input variable for PowerShell script from Step Functions than from simple Lambda?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at option 2 I specified in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514998/9115027 see if using that format you are able to get the parameters

Comment: I used your advice in option 2 and it works! Thanks @Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joe's comment leading to his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514998/9115027) I managed to form the appropriate definition of State Machines to pass the Parameter to PowerShell Lambda script:

```
{
  "Comment": "Start Script",
  "StartAt": "PowerShellScript1",
  "States": {
    "PowerShellScript1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:XYZ:function:PowerShellScript1:$LATEST",
      "Parameters": {
        "tokens": "ABC123"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```